# Flutter: How to determine cacheSize of Images before launch?

Tags: flutter, responsive-images

The Flutter DevTools displayed the message: `Consider resizing the asset ahead of time, supplying a cacheWidth parameter of 35, a cacheHeight parameter of 35, or using a ResizeImage.`
Because my image size depends on the screen size I am searching for a way to set it dynamically.
I attempted that by using a `LayoutBuilder` but it feels a little bit too complicated to do this with every image.

Has anybody already experience with that and give any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes I get it too